# My HTML button redirects me to this weird "Index of C:\" thing. How do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html

When I click the submit button on my form validation script it sends me to this strange "Index of C:\" page. I am a newb following a tutorial, I get this error but my code is the same as in the tutorial.

I think the error has to do with my file path linking my HTML to my javascript

The Submit button is supposed to do nothing when pressed, it shows me this strange page when pressed.
I've tried several different types of syntax for linking the javascript to the HTML, none have worked. At one point I could put the files in the same folder and t

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/JS.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="error"></div>
    <form action="/" method="POST">
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" type = "text">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input id="password" name="password" type = "password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
const name = document.getElementById('name')
const password = document.getElementById('password')
const form = document.getElementById('form')

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
})
```

I am trying to learn form validation and got stuck on this problem today.

Comment: Your form action redirects to the root here `<form action="/" method="POST">`. Remove the action attribute

Comment: Is there anything in your javascript error console? For example, something complaining about `undefined` not having an `addEventListener` property?

Answer (score 1):

When you're loading your document from `file:///`, `<form action="/">` will always redirect you to `C:\`. The tutorial expects you to have deployed your site somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `action` attribute, add it only when you deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Your listener does not catch the event. You can also play with action.

Try to change both:

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
```

into

```
<form id="form" action="" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the action stuff from the form, will add that back if I put it on the internet. This code is just for practice.